# Are there any differences in calling function using this and not using this?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
Class::Class() {
    this->func();
}
```

and

```
Class::Class() {
    func();
}
```

Are there any differences between these two ways of calling a function?

Comment: The first one requires you to type more.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore What if `func()` is virtual, they are still equivalent?

Comment: @leeleo3x `this` exists in non static member functions.

Comment: It's just what I want, thank you. @remyabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this->var ensures you're working with instance variable - which may be useful when your instance variables may be shadowed inside a block.